# LKM How to unblock vfs_read()?

Tags: kernel-module

I have a kernel module that I need to read data from a serial port. I use filp_open() to open the serial port device and then, on a thread, I call vfs_read() on a loop to get data from the serial device.

The problem is when I want to rmmod the module.  I don't know how to "unblock" vfs_read since it will be blocked until new data is available on the serial port.

I tried to both sending a signal and calling wake_up_process on the vfs_read thread, but none of them worked.

I know I could open the serial port with O_NONBLOCK, but I want to avoid having to keeping polling the device for new data.

Thanks

Comment: You cannot "unblock" the `read` call which is currently executed. But you may send a signal to the process which performs it. Common `kill` should be sufficient for `vfs_read` to return with an error value. Assuming your code catches error values, you should be able to return from your code and allow the module to be unloaded.

Comment: I tried sending a signal to the blocking pid and it partially worked:  the blocking vfs_read returned and I was able to then to close the port, but then if a try to open it again, the vfs_read won't read anything anymore from the serial port (looks like that unblocking with a signal left the port in an error state) - tried too to read the serial port with another software (picocom) e and didn't either (serial port died - had to restart the system).